# How to get parameters from RequestBody in Spring REST controller method

Tags: java, json, rest, post

In a Spring Boot application I have the following method signature in a `Controller`:

```
@PostMapping(value="/borrow")
public ResponseEntity<Void> postBorrowBook(@RequestBody String personId, 
                                           @RequestBody String bookId) {    
    LOG.info(RESTController.class.getName() + ".postBorrowBook() method called.");   

    ...

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);        
}
```

I want to get the values of the two parameters from the `RequestBody`.

Can anyone let me know how this be done if the request I am making is JSON as follows:

```
{"personId":"207","bookId":"5"}
```

I am currently receiving:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-06-17T20:59:37.330+0000",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Void> com.city2018.webapps.code.controller.RESTController.postBorrowBook(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)",
"path": "/rest/borrow/"
}
```

I already have the following working in a similar scenario for simple non-REST requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/borrow", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postBorrowBook(@RequestParam("personId") String personId, 
                                 @RequestParam("bookId") String bookId,
                                 Model model) {    
        LOG.info(PersonController.class.getName() + ".postBorrowBook() method called.");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a POJO with 2 fields (**personId** and **bookId**) and change your signature as follow:

```
@PostMapping(value="/borrow")
public ResponseEntity<Void> postBorrowBook(@RequestBody RequestDTO requestBody) {
    requestBody.getPersonId();
    requestBody.getBookId();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First you should define a POJO class as:

   public class BorrowBookEntity{ 
       public String personId; 
       public String bookId; 
   }
2. Then you rely on spring to get the value as:

   ```
   @PostMapping("/request")
   public ResponseEntity<Void> postController(
          @RequestBody BorrowBookEntity borrowBookEntity) {
   ...
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try another . 
e.g. @RequestBodyParam

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveData", headers="Content-Type=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveData(@RequestBodyParam String source,@RequestBodyParam JsonDto json) throws MyException {
    ...
}
```

https://github.com/LambdaExpression/RequestBodyParam